# ScrollView inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a Coordinator Layout, where I have on top of it a player info bar and at the bottom a navigation bar, which are fixed there. In the middle I have a relative layout which contains a scroll view and the problem is, that the scroll view doesnt scroll. Additionally to that I have put for test purposes a  border around the relative layout inside of the scroll view and as you can see, the size of the layout is way smaller than it should be.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainCoordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.felix043.thedungeon.Main.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Player Infos -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_playerinfo"></include>

    <!-- ViewPager -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/QuestRelLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_viewpager">
        </include>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playerinfo"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavLayout">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/playerinfo"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavLayout">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavLayout"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/playerinfo"
                    android:background="@drawable/text_border">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/button7"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button8"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/button10"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:text="Button" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- BottomNav -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_navbar"></include>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
As the blue lines showes, there are more buttons above the scroll view, but I cant scroll.

Expected result: The scroll view is as big as the screen without the player info and the navigation bar and it should be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two ways

1- add minHeight in your scrollview

```
  <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/playerinfo"
                android:minHeight="200dp" //change as per your requirement
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavLayout">
```

2- use linearlayout with **weight** it will automatically adjust screen size.

Comment: The first point with minHeigth does make the scrollview bigger as I wanted to, but somehow the relative layout inside doesnt change, even if i have match_parent.
The second point with linearlayout and weight give me the same result. Somehow to relative layout inside the scroll view wont adjust.